# When using hyper-v virtual machine and running a game why the game window is so small and can't be maximize?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

on my original main system i have windows 10 pro and i created a new virtual machine using hyper-v and installed on the virtual machine windows 8.1 pro

screenshot of the game window i marked it with red circle. i can't open/maximize it.

[image: hyper-v game window]

Answer (score 0):

The game
[Battlefield: Bad Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield:_Bad_Company)
was released on 2008.
At that time, the current
[Windows version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)
was Windows Vista, which is a far cry from Windows 8.1 that was
released in 2013.

To try and signal to Windows 8.1 that the game was made for an older
Windows version, do this:

- Find the game's executable (`.exe`) in Explorer
- Right-click the file and select Properties
- Go to the Compatibility tab
- Place a check-mark next to "Run this program in compatibility mode for:"
- In the drop-down list select one of the Windows Vista variants
- Click OK.

Now try the game (keeping your fingers crossed).

If it doesn't work, perhaps it will work in a virtual machine
that uses Windows Vista. However, I note that some games do not work in
virtual machines, because they support badly the emulated hardware.